# iOS rasterization SVG or other vector graphics ? i want get texture for openGL from my vector graphics !

Tags: ios, svg, render

Hi i want rasterize SVG or other vector graphics on iOS !

i want get texture from vector graphics in realTime or in preloader and render him in my openGL graphics engine ))

what lib can get me texture from SVG ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly the question but you may want to look at [SVGKit](https://github.com/mattrajca/SVGKit).